# Dead lock on SYS object during oracle EXPDP

Tags: oracle, export, deadlock

I have an Oracle 11g and I wanted to export all my shcema objects,

with this command:

```
expdp as '/ as sysdba' directory=DIR dumpfile=DWH%U.dmp logfile=DWH.log filesize=40000m parallel=32 schemas=DWH
```

This is the start of the output I'v got:

```
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 1840. GB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.
ORA-39029: worker 14 with process name "DW0D" prematurely terminated
ORA-31671: Worker process DW0D had an unhandled exception.
ORA-39078: unable to dequeue message for agent KUPC$A_1_100742920000000 from queue "KUPC$C_1_20190915100610"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 610
ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object SYS.KUPC$C_1_20190915100610
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 1887
ORA-06512: at line 2
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/AUDIT_OBJ
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/RLS_POLICY/RLS_POLICY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYNONYM/RLS_POLICY/RLS_POLICY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/BITMAP_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/BITMAP_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/JOB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/REFRESH_GROUP
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/POST_SCHEMA/PROCOBJ
. . exported "DWH"."T3"                            9.119 GB 21698829
```

The exception occured but the export hasn't failed.. and I can see that the tables start to be exported.

What is this exception mean? deadlock on object of sys? I can see that the object "KUPC$C_1_20190915100610" is a queue of SYS.. Should I need to restart my export or can I use it after finished?

Thank you.

Comment: Normal deadlock errors generate a trace file.  I'm not sure if `ORA-04020` counts as a normal deadlock, but you might want to look for the file anyway.  It might have useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue last month and found a way to solve it.
Try to run the following commands:

```
grant flashback any table to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.KU$_USER_MAPPING_VIEW to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.FGA_LOG$FOR_EXPORT to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.AUDTAB$TBS$FOR_EXPORT to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.DBA_SENSITIVE_DATA to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.DBA_TSDP_POLICY_PROTECTION to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.NACL$_ACE_EXP to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.NACL$_HOST_EXP to exp_full_database;
grant flashback on SYS.NACL$_WALLET_EXP to exp_full_database;
```